# How to calculate CRC-16 from HEX values?

Tags: objective-c, hex, crc, polynomial-math

In my code i need to calculate CRC-16 16 bit values for the HEX values stored as NSdata, below is the code snippet to calculate CRC-16 in c.

```
   void UpdateCRC(unsigned short int *CRC, unsigned char x)
{
  // This function uses the initial CRC value passed in the first
  // argument, then modifies it using the single character passed
  // as the second argument, according to a CRC-16 polynomial
  // Arguments:
  //   CRC -- pointer to starting CRC value
  //   x   -- new character to be processed
  // Returns:
  // The function does not return any values, but updates the variable
  // pointed to by CRC
static int const Poly = 0xA001;
int i;
bool flag;
*CRC ^= x;
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
// CRC-16 polynomial
{
  flag = ((*CRC & 1) == 1);
  *CRC = (unsigned short int)(*CRC >> 1);
  if (flag)
      *CRC ^= Poly;
  }
return; 
}
```

NSdata which holds the hex values like below

```
const char connectByteArray[] = {
    0x21,0x01,0x90,0x80,0x5F
};
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes: connectByteArray length:sizeof(connectByteArray)];
```

Comment: First thing you need to do is store your data in the appropriate data type, which isn't `NSString`.  Convert the data to `NSData` and try this code to get the CRC16 value: http://svn.mulle-kybernetik.com/edframeworks/edcommon/trunk/FoundationExtensions.subproj/NSData+Extensions.m

Comment: Thanks for your answer i tried converting it in appropriate data types but i was not getting correct response, i can get mod bus and modem CCITT CRC but not CRC 16 with 0xA001 polynomial...any example or code snippets will help me a lot??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using the following C program, I hope it may help someone ..cheers!!!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


const int order = 16;
const unsigned long polynom = 0x8005;
const int direct = 1;
const unsigned long crcinit = 0;
const unsigned long crcxor = 0;
const int refin = 1;
const int refout = 1;

// 'order' [1..32] is the CRC polynom order, counted without the leading '1' bit
// 'polynom' is the CRC polynom without leading '1' bit
// 'direct' [0,1] specifies the kind of algorithm: 1=direct, no augmented zero bits
// 'crcinit' is the initial CRC value belonging to that algorithm
// 'crcxor' is the final XOR value
// 'refin' [0,1] specifies if a data byte is reflected before processing (UART) or not
// 'refout' [0,1] specifies if the CRC will be reflected before XOR


// Data character string

const unsigned char string[] = {0x05,0x0f,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x99};

// internal global values:

unsigned long crcmask;
unsigned long crchighbit;
unsigned long crcinit_direct;
unsigned long crcinit_nondirect;
unsigned long crctab[256];


// subroutines

unsigned long reflect (unsigned long crc, int bitnum) {

    // reflects the lower 'bitnum' bits of 'crc'

    unsigned long i, j=1, crcout=0;

    for (i=(unsigned long)1<<(bitnum-1); i; i>>=1) {
        if (crc & i) crcout|=j;
        j<<= 1;
    }
    return (crcout);
}



void generate_crc_table() {

    // make CRC lookup table used by table algorithms

    int i, j;
    unsigned long bit, crc;

    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {

        crc=(unsigned long)i;
        if (refin) crc=reflect(crc, 8);
        crc<<= order-8;

        for (j=0; j<8; j++) {

            bit = crc & crchighbit;
            crc<<= 1;
            if (bit) crc^= polynom;
        }           

        if (refin) crc = reflect(crc, order);
        crc&= crcmask;
        crctab[i]= crc;
    }
}



unsigned long crctablefast (unsigned char* p, unsigned long len) {

    // fast lookup table algorithm without augmented zero bytes, e.g. used in pkzip.
    // only usable with polynom orders of 8, 16, 24 or 32.

    unsigned long crc = crcinit_direct;

    if (refin) crc = reflect(crc, order);

    if (!refin) while (len--) crc = (crc << 8) ^ crctab[ ((crc >> (order-8)) & 0xff) ^ *p++];
    else while (len--) crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crctab[ (crc & 0xff) ^ *p++];

    if (refout^refin) crc = reflect(crc, order);
    crc^= crcxor;
    crc&= crcmask;

    return(crc);
}



unsigned long crctable (unsigned char* p, unsigned long len) {

    // normal lookup table algorithm with augmented zero bytes.
    // only usable with polynom orders of 8, 16, 24 or 32.

    unsigned long crc = crcinit_nondirect;

    if (refin) crc = reflect(crc, order);

    if (!refin) while (len--) crc = ((crc << 8) | *p++) ^ crctab[ (crc >> (order-8))  & 0xff];
    else while (len--) crc = ((crc >> 8) | (*p++ << (order-8))) ^ crctab[ crc & 0xff];

    if (!refin) while (++len < order/8) crc = (crc << 8) ^ crctab[ (crc >> (order-8))  & 0xff];
    else while (++len < order/8) crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crctab[crc & 0xff];

    if (refout^refin) crc = reflect(crc, order);
    crc^= crcxor;
    crc&= crcmask;

    return(crc);
}



unsigned long crcbitbybit(unsigned char* p, unsigned long len) {

    // bit by bit algorithm with augmented zero bytes.
    // does not use lookup table, suited for polynom orders between 1...32.

    unsigned long i, j, c, bit;
    unsigned long crc = crcinit_nondirect;

    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {

        c = (unsigned long)*p++;
        if (refin) c = reflect(c, 8);

        for (j=0x80; j; j>>=1) {

            bit = crc & crchighbit;
            crc<<= 1;
            if (c & j) crc|= 1;
            if (bit) crc^= polynom;
        }
    }   

    for (i=0; i<order; i++) {

        bit = crc & crchighbit;
        crc<<= 1;
        if (bit) crc^= polynom;
    }

    if (refout) crc=reflect(crc, order);
    crc^= crcxor;
    crc&= crcmask;

    return(crc);
}



unsigned long crcbitbybitfast(unsigned char* p, unsigned long len) {

    // fast bit by bit algorithm without augmented zero bytes.
    // does not use lookup table, suited for polynom orders between 1...32.

    unsigned long i, j, c, bit;
    unsigned long crc = crcinit_direct;

    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {

        c = (unsigned long)*p++;
        if (refin) c = reflect(c, 8);

        for (j=0x80; j; j>>=1) {

            bit = crc & crchighbit;
            crc<<= 1;
            if (c & j) bit^= crchighbit;
            if (bit) crc^= polynom;
        }
    }   

    if (refout) crc=reflect(crc, order);
    crc^= crcxor;
    crc&= crcmask;

    return(crc);
}



int main() {

    // test program for checking four different CRC computing types that are:
    // crcbit(), crcbitfast(), crctable() and crctablefast(), see above.
    // parameters are at the top of this program.
    // Result will be printed on the console.

    int i;
    unsigned long bit, crc;


    // at first, compute constant bit masks for whole CRC and CRC high bit

    crcmask = ((((unsigned long)1<<(order-1))-1)<<1)|1;
    crchighbit = (unsigned long)1<<(order-1);


    // check parameters

    if (order < 1 || order > 32) {
        printf("ERROR, invalid order, it must be between 1..32.\n");
        return(0);
    }

    if (polynom != (polynom & crcmask)) {
        printf("ERROR, invalid polynom.\n");
        return(0);
    }

    if (crcinit != (crcinit & crcmask)) {
        printf("ERROR, invalid crcinit.\n");
        return(0);
    }

    if (crcxor != (crcxor & crcmask)) {
        printf("ERROR, invalid crcxor.\n");
        return(0);
    }


    // generate lookup table

    generate_crc_table();


    // compute missing initial CRC value

    if (!direct) {

        crcinit_nondirect = crcinit;
        crc = crcinit;
        for (i=0; i<order; i++) {

            bit = crc & crchighbit;
            crc<<= 1;
            if (bit) crc^= polynom;
        }
        crc&= crcmask;
        crcinit_direct = crc;
    }

    else {

        crcinit_direct = crcinit;
        crc = crcinit;
        for (i=0; i<order; i++) {

            bit = crc & 1;
            if (bit) crc^= polynom;
            crc >>= 1;
            if (bit) crc|= crchighbit;
        }   
        crcinit_nondirect = crc;
    }


    // call CRC algorithms using the CRC parameters above and print result to the console

    printf("\n");
    printf("CRC tester v1.1 written on 13/01/2003 by Sven Reifegerste (zorc/reflex)\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Parameters:\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" polynom             :  0x%x\n", polynom);
    printf(" order               :  %d\n", order);
    printf(" crcinit             :  0x%x direct, 0x%x nondirect\n", crcinit_direct, crcinit_nondirect);
    printf(" crcxor              :  0x%x\n", crcxor);
    printf(" refin               :  %d\n", refin);
    printf(" refout              :  %d\n", refout);
    printf("\n");
    printf(" data string         :  '%s' (%d bytes)\n", string, strlen(string));
    printf("\n");
    printf("Results:\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf(" crc bit by bit      :  0x%x\n", crcbitbybit((unsigned char *)string, 6));
    printf(" crc bit by bit fast :  0x%x\n", crcbitbybitfast((unsigned char *)string, strlen(string)));
    if (!(order&7)) printf(" crc table           :  0x%x\n", crctable((unsigned char *)string, strlen(string)));
    if (!(order&7)) printf(" crc table fast      :  0x%x\n", crctablefast((unsigned char *)string, strlen(string)));

    return(0);
}
```